# Custom Camera Rotation problems

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, rotation

I have a custom camera overlay that, like all camera views, is default in landscape mode. I have some orientation change logic that detect when the orientation changes so I can rotate the buttons and views that I have placed. Also, I have edited the shouldAutoRotateInterfaceTo method so it does not rotate while the camera is on:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
               (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation  {
        if (cameraIsOn) {
            return NO;
        }
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

**Problem**: the camera view still rotates into Portrait mode when I tilt the camera into Landscape. This results in the device being in Landscape position while the view is in Portrait, running off of the screen.

If it helps, here is the method I use to detect orientation changes and transform my buttons:

```
- (void)cameraOrientationChanged  {
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
CGAffineTransform transform;
switch (orientation) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.rotatePrompt.hidden = NO;
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        //transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180*M_PI/180);
        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.rotatePrompt.hidden = NO;
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        //transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90*M_PI/180);
        self.rotatePrompt.hidden = YES;
        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        //transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90.0*M_PI/180);
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180*M_PI/180);
        self.rotatePrompt.hidden = YES;
        break;
    default:
        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        break;
}
self.shootButton.transform = transform;
self.cameraTypeButton.transform = transform;
self.photoLibraryButton.transform = transform;
self.changeCameraDirectionButton.transform = transform;
self.flashButton.transform = transform;
self.videoTimerLabel.transform = transform;
self.closeCameraButton.transform = transform;
```

}

**Note** This seemed to be working ok before I upgraded to iOS 5.

**More Info** 
By looking at my Xib file, I can see that I created the overlay in Portrait mode. When the camera overlay rotates it is moving into Portrait mode while the device is being help in Landscape position.

Even more peculiar, whenever this happens (it does not always happen), I noticed that shouldAutorotateToInderfaceOrientation is not being called in the view controller. I bet that has something to do with the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with my navigation controller setup. UIImagePickerController sends the rotation message to the root view controller's shouldAutoRotateToInterface: method. However, since I copied the class from an older project (iOS 3), it did not have the shouldAutoRotateToInterface: method automatically copied. Now that I wrote the method in my root view controller, to rotation problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `UIDeviceOrientation` when you really should be using `UIInterfaceOrientation`.  `UIDeviceOrientation` has many more states than `UIInterfaceOrientation`, so this could result in a device state being something other than what you were expecting for an interface state, for instance `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` can be returned even when the interface orientation (to the user) looks like it should be `UIInterfaceOrienataionLandscape`.  So in your case, your `default` switch case may be returning more often than you would expect for it to.

If it were me, I would change your `- (void)cameraOrientationChanged` method to `- (void)cameraOrientationChangedTo:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation` and call that method in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation  {

    [self cameraOrientationChangeTo:interfaceOrientation];

    if (cameraIsOn) {
        return NO;
    }

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

`UIDeviceOrientation` vs `UIInterfaceOrientation`:

```
typedef enum {
   UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
} UIDeviceOrientation;

typedef enum {
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
} UIInterfaceOrientation;
```

Comment: I did exactly as you've described. I think your method is better since I do not need to create a notification for view changes myself, however, this has not stopped the view from rotating.

Comment: Are you trying to not rotate `self.cameraImagePicker.view`?  If so, remove `self.cameraImagePicker.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;` and see if that does anything, even though it really shouldn't if the view controller is telling the views not to rotate...

Comment: tried that too. nothing. something peculiar - the build works fine on my device when i am building it from xcode. when i release the app on testflight is the only time i see this camera issue.

Comment: Try turning on optimization in your compile settings for debug mode.  I've heard of some issues with LLVM and iOS5 with optimization.

Comment: tried that too. my debug build still works fine. this is a very frustrating problem :(

Comment: I added some more info on the problem I am having. Any ideas would help.