# how to rotate camera preview mode in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to rotate a `UIImage` while capturing an image using the camera. However, I am getting the preview in `portrait` mode only. How do I display the preview image in `landscape` mode?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039383/custom-camera-rotation-problems :)

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039383/custom-camera-rotation-problems :). Maybe it would help you. Thanks

Comment: @Gill that answer will not help in iOS 6, where `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is never called.

Comment: @WayneHartman the question was not asked for iOS6... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reading the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) for `UIImagePickerController` reveals this interesting tidbit:

> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This
>   class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.

Despite Apple's warning, there is one way of doing things:

You can subscribe to rotation notifications in a delegate class:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Then, based on the current rotation of the device, you can apply a `CGAffineTransform` to your overlay view.  An example of this kind of transform can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039383/custom-camera-rotation-problems).  That particular answer will not help you in iOS 6, because the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` calls will never be made to your `UIViewController` subclass. Your best version strategy will be to subscribe to the notifications.  Keep in mind that you're going full manual here and your best bet is to figure out a way to only support portrait mode.

Also, make sure to balance the notification calls with this call when finished:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```