# How to keep the orientation from being rotated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation

I am working on an iPad app the uses landscape only orientation. It has a feature to click on a UIImageView to access the camera roll and pick a pic from there and then display it.

The app goes like this. I have a table vie that when you click the '+'button it loads a new view to add a new data to the database. This 'add' page loads in modal mode.

The problem is that whenever the camera roll gets loaded it automatically changes the orientation to portrait and I wanted the whole app to keep landscape oriented.

So anyone have a solution?

Video link:  [Video showing the problem](http://youtu.be/8JdGXzzgKO8)

Answer (score 0):

if your application is based on UINavigationController then use the following category method

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation)

    #pragma From UINavigationController

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

        return TRUE;
    }
    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft || UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Landscape mode ViewController,

```
#pragma mark - iOS 5.0 and up Rotation Methods

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

}

#pragma mark - iOS 6.0 and up Rotation Methods

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

If you are using navigationController,
Create a category like this,

```
    @interface UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

    @end

    @implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
        return YES;
    }

    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        return [[self topViewController] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }

@end
```

Comment: In supported interface orientations, are you enable landscape mode?

Comment: enable landscape mode and disable portrait mode.

Comment: I did that at the beginning of the project. Still doesn't work.

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO]; try this in appdelegate didFinishLaunch method.

Comment: Didn't work. Now it came to my mind is it because I am working on iOS 7 and Xcode 5?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. And use required orientations as shown below.

```
// For responding to the user accepting a newly-captured picture or movie
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

    UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage;

    editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                               UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                 UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if (originalImage) {
        [uploadImageBtn setHidden:NO];
        UIImage* newImage ;
        switch (originalImage.imageOrientation) {
            case UIImageOrientationUp: //Left
            case UIImageOrientationDown: //Right
            {
                newImage  = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:originalImage.CGImage scale:originalImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
            }
                break;
            case UIImageOrientationLeft: //Down
            case UIImageOrientationRight: //Up
            {
                newImage = originalImage;
            }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        capturedImage.image = newImage;
    }

    [cameraUI dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

}
```

Comment: Am I wrong or you think the problem is with the UIImageView dealing with the image? If so, I think it is not the issue because the problem comes when the camera roll view gets loaded. Not within my app.

Comment: Check this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039383/custom-camera-rotation-problems)

Comment: Still nothing.. You know I think I can't change that since camera roll is an Apple app and I think I can't modify it's behavior..

Comment: I'll post a video on youtube so that you can see what's happening.